# How to only accept e-mail from a single IP address

Tags: postfix

I am sure this is a simple question but I've been Googling for days now and am not making much progress, forgive me if this has been asked previously.  I'm new to Linux and am still getting to grips with the basics, but am beginning to get a feel for things.

I have Postfix 2.11 installed as an MTA.  We receive mail from a Smarthost to our router, redirect all incoming port 25 traffic to Postfix where amavis and spamassassin do their work, then send it on to our Exchange box.  This all works perfectly.

However, I notice in the mail.log file that the vast majority of SPAM does not come from the smarthost, it's received directly by Postfix from the internet.  The smarthost always uses the same IP address.  Is there a way I can tell Postfix to only accept incoming mail from this single IP address and reject everything else, or are there risks involved in this that I'm not seeing?

Comment: It's running on Ubuntu 14.04 and I downloaded from official Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 4):

Well, turns out this was indeed very easy.

In main.cf include the IP address of the SmartHost:

> mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

and add this line to the end of the main.cf file:

> smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject

Reload postfix:

> sudo postfix reload

Now any connections from IP addresses not included in `mynetworks` will be rejected.

Comment: Note that, depending on your `smtpd_relay_restrictions`, editing `mynetworks` like this may also allow the smarthost to also send outgoing mail to other domains (not just mail that will be delivered locally).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest manner in which to accomplish this would be to go back to your router, and modify the rule redirecting port 25 traffic to your Ubuntu machine.  Allow it to only redirect traffic from your smarthost, and dump the rest.

Comment: Thanks Charles.  An excellent suggestion and one I hadn't though of.  Unfortunately this customer is using a Draytek 2820 which doesn't seem to support port redirection with filtering by source.  However, I am grateful for your suggestion and will keep it in mind for future reference.

Comment: That's too bad.  I suppose that there may be a way to limit this in postfix, but I'm not familiar with the program myself.

Comment: Postfix seems like a solid, highly configurable piece of software, unfortunately I am also very unfamiliar with it.  But thank you for your suggestion.